# Struggling with Analysis inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, absolute-value, epsilon-delta

I have always struggled with Analysis... I understand the concepts generally I feel like, but when I go to show something or try and prove something I feel my symbolic notation is awful.  I know that

$$\left|{{\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}-f'(z_0)}}\right|\le\epsilon$$

implies

$$|f(z)-f(z_0)-(z-z_0)f'(z_0)|<\epsilon|z-z_0|$$

But why is it okay to drop the absolute value signs below, which was presented to be true in a chapter I'm reading...

$$f(z)=f(z_0)+(z-z_0)f'(z_0)+\eta\cdot(z-z_0)$$

with $|\eta|=|\eta(z)|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Do you mean to finish with "$\leq \epsilon |z - z_0|$ on the "implies"?

Comment: oh yes.... sorry.  I fixed it.

Comment: both sides are positive

Comment: define eta such that the equality holds for eta positive, then you can leave the abs values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rafael Wagner has the idea right, but it is cleaner to approach it in this fashion:

Define $\eta = \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}-f'(z_0)$. (Note that $\eta$ is a function of $z$ and $z_0$.)

Then $$f(z) = f(z_0) + f'(z_0)(z - z_0) + \eta(z - z_0)$$

And by the existance of $f'(z_0)$, we know that for any $\epsilon > 0$, when $z$ is sufficiently close to $z_0, |\eta| < \epsilon$.

Comment: that was great.  thank you!